# External POST request on IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

We need to take post parameter from the external form. Example:

1st application - Form

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="privet" value="TestValue" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>
```

1st application - Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(string privet)
{
    return Content("Answer: " + privet);
}
```

2nd application (**external**) -- Controller

```
WebRequest _wr = WebRequest.Create("http://SomeExternalDomain/Home/Test");
 _wr.Method = "POST";
byte[] byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("privet=SomeValue");
_wr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
_wr.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
using (Stream dataStream = _wr.GetRequestStream())
{
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
}


using (HttpWebResponse _response = (HttpWebResponse)_wr.GetResponse())
{
    using (Stream _dataStream = _response.GetResponseStream())
    {
         using (StreamReader _reader = new StreamReader(_dataStream))
         {
             return _reader.ReadToEnd();
         }
    }
}
```

If we send Post within a single application, post data accepted, but from external application, post discarded. (Instead of POST, on the method comes GET withoud data).

On IIS logs registered POST request in both cases.

`2014-02-20 13:59:45 ::1 POST /Home/Test ...`

`2014-02-20 14:12:41 192.168.15.18 POST /Home/Test ...`

---

Where can be limited external post requests? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine. It could be simplified to:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection
    {
        { "privet", "SomeValue" },
    };
    byte[] result = client.UploadValues("http://SomeExternalDomain/Home/Test", values);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result);
}
```

but I guess that won't resolve the issue. You seem to have mentioned something about a GET request. Maybe your external application is a web application and you are redirecting the client browser after making the POST request.